# linq over strings C#

Tags: c#, linq, string

Could someone please give an example of how to use ling to query over a long string of text and find a substring within that string?

regards

Comment: Can you give an example of the string and the substring you want to search for. Doesn't String.Substring() fit your need ?

Comment: Can you give a sample string? It is better to use regex for text parsing.

Comment: Sort of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028846

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wouldn't use LINQ, I would use [`String.Substring`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx), or a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

Can you post an example of the string you would like to search and an example of a substring you would like to find within that string?

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var found = "Where in the world is Carmen Sandiego".Split(' ').Where(part => part.StartsWith("i"));
    foreach (var part in found)
        Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making a leap here, but if you want to find a *word* within a long string and pick it out based on some criteria using LINQ, you could do something like this...

```
private static string longString = "This is a really long string";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = from word in longString.Split(' ')
                where word.StartsWith("r")
                select word;
}
```

I'm saying nothing about whether LINQ is an appropriate technology here.